# scons: warning: Calling missing SConscript without error is deprecated

Tags: c, build, scons

I am trying to build a simple printing HelloWorld using the scons build tool.

My helloWorld.c file contains:

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main()
{
printf("Hello, world!\n");
}
```

My SConstruct contains:

```
Program(["helloWorld.c"])
```

When I run scons, I get result as following but no executable output:

PS D:\01_code> scons -f SCOnstruct
scons: Reading SConscript files ...

scons: warning: Calling missing SConscript without error is deprecated.
Transition by adding must_exist=0 to SConscript calls.
Missing SConscript 'SCOnstruct'
File "C:\Python27\Scripts\scons", line 204, in 
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `.' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.
PS D:\01_code>

My aim is to learn the scons build tool.
i have Windows 10, Python 27, latest scons

Comment: I have no idea on how to use scons, but if scons is only a replacement for make and you are trying to quickly compile in C your helloworld.c , you only need to type : gcc helloworld.c and you get and executable file. On linux your file will be called a.out

Comment: See my response below. Any chance you can share a github repo with your example? That may help us see what's going on? Also which version of Python? Which version of SCons?

Answer (score 1):

Lots of small errors that I see:

HelloWorld.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   printf("Hello, world!\n");
}
```

SConstruct

```
Program('HelloWorld',['HelloWorld.h'])
```

Running this will yield

```
# Note no need to specify -f SConstruct. SConstruct is the default file SCons will look for.
$scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gcc -o HelloWorld.o -c HelloWorld.c
gcc -o HelloWorld HelloWorld.o
scons: done building targets.
```

Given your example I have no idea how you got a warning like this.

```
scons: warning: Calling missing SConscript without error is deprecated.
```

I even tried calling as you did with -f SConstruct

```
$scons -f SConstruct
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gcc -o HelloWorld.o -c HelloWorld.c
gcc -o HelloWorld HelloWorld.o
scons: done building targets.
```

Answer (score 0):

scons will print the warning message "Calling missing SConscript" if you refer to a SConstruct/SConscript file that scons can not find.

In this case, I would guess that you're running scons from a different directory than the location of your SConstruct and HelloWorld.c file.

There are a couple other problems that you should address.

1. You say your C file is named *HelloWorld.c*, but your SConstruct refers to *hello.c*
2. Your Program declaration should provide a name for the output, e.g. `Program('hello', ['HelloWorld.c'])`
3. Your *HelloWorld.c* should contain a printf call, not just a string value.